# Nesting function call

Tags: jquery

I want the notify to occur only after the unblock event, however both occur together. I am pretty new to JQuery.

```
function isSuccess()
            {
                $(function () {
                  setTimeout('unblock()',1000);
                  $.notifyBar({
                    html: "Thank you, your settings were updated!",
                    delay: 2000,
                    animationSpeed: "normal"
                  });

                });

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `notifyBar` to be executed after `unblock`, place it after `unblock`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    unblock();
    $.notifyBar({
        ...
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: Thanks Nikita, would'nt it delay the notify by 1 sec also since its included in setTimeOut ?

Comment: @Popo Darin has clarified it in his comment

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        unblock();
        $.notifyBar({
            html: "Thank you, your settings were updated!",
            delay: 2000,
            animationSpeed: "normal"
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, can you tell me why did my code did not worked and yours did. I thought first setTimeout would last for 1 second, then the notify bar would occur but they both occured simultaneously, Popo.

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't last for 1 second. It waits one second before executing the method without blocking meaning that it will immediately call the `notifyBar` function. One second later the unblock will be called and 2 seconds later the notify bar. With the new code, we wait 1 second, then we unblock and 2 seconds later we show the notification bar.

Answer (score 1):

wrap in another anonymous function

```
function isSuccess()
{
    $(function () {
        function unblockAndNotify() {
            unblock();
            $.notifyBar({
                html: "Thank you, your settings were updated!",
                delay: 2000,
                animationSpeed: "normal"
            });
        }
        setTimeout(unblockAndNotify,1000);
    });
}
```

EDIT: I was going to do what Darin did and declare the function inline with the setTimeout, but didn't want to introduce too many new concepts at once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-arrange the order of calls.
Either you have to call `$.notifyBar()` from within `unblock()` or you are doing something like

```
setTimeout(function(){
   unblock();
   $.notifyBar({
          html: "Thank you, your settings were updated!",
          delay: 2000,
          animationSpeed: "normal"
   });
}, 1000);
```